# Como fazer incremento continuo com Touchable do React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, touch

Existe alguma propriedade no `TouchableOpacity` do React Native que, quando eu pressionasse o botão de incremento e ficasse segurando o toque, continuasse incrementando os valores?

Por exemplo, tenho esse botão:

```
<TouchableOpacity
   style={styles.button} 
   onPress={()=>increment(item.id,item.amount)}
 >
  <Text> + </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Que renderiza assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de, ao continuar pressionando o botão, continuar incrementando o valor.

Answer (score -1):

Olá, o TouchableOpacity e o TouchableWithoutFeedback tem as opções de onPressIn e onPressOut, acredito que isso ajude a resolver o problema.

Você pode ter um estado controlando se o botão ainda esta sendo pressionado e fazer um loop para ir incrementando.

Comment: Olá, Iury! Sua resposta pode solucionar o problema, mas sugiro que coloque o código necessário para reproduzí-la (leia sobre [mcve]). Ao colocar o código, sua resposta terá mais valor para visitantes futuros (e também para o autor da pergunta), pois facilitará o entendimento e a reprodução da solução.

Answer (score -1):

A forma que encontrei foi usando `onPressIn` e `onPressOut` com `setTimeout`.

```
const App = () => {

 const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
 const [timer,setTimer] = useState(null);

const handlePressIn = () =>{
 // A cada 200ms enquanto estiver pressionando o botão ele vai 
 // executar a função
 setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1);
 setTimer(setTimeout(handlePressIn, 200));
}

const handlePressOut = () =>{
 clearTimeout(timer);
}

return ( ... )
```

Agora vou tentar replicar para meu caso de uso.